# How do I put several forms to show in a summarized page using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, save

My problem is that I have made six different forms `1.php`, `2.php`, `3.php`, `4.php`, `5.php` and `6.php` but I want the result from the all the different forms to show on a summarized page.

The six different forms are going to be given to six different persons and they will all have their own page that their submitted text are going to show.

Let us say that I tell them to write their favorite food it will be something like this:

```
Person 1 types in the form at 1.php that sends it to 1food.php through $_POST
Person 2 types in the form at 2.php that sends it to 2food.php through $_POST
Person 3 types in the form at 3.php that sends it to 3food.php through $_POST
Person 4 types in the form at 4.php that sends it to 4food.php through $_POST
Person 5 types in the form at 1.php that sends it to 5food.php through $_POST
Person 6 types in the form at 1.php that sends it to 6food.php through $_POST
```

Now there are six different pages with six different food, the problem is that I want these to be saved permanently on each page until they type in something new. Another problem is that I also want to get the information from all the six pages to a summarized page.

The summarized page needs to contain the food that all the six persons wrote permanently until their forms gets new input.

The new page **summarizedfood.php** have to show all the results from 1food.php, 2food.php, 3food.php, 4food.php, 5food.php and 6food.php and to be saved.

The reason for **summarizedfood.php** to save what they wrote is to give a link like https://examplelink.com/summarizedfood.php to anyone or anywhere and it will show what they answered.

I have searched through the internet how to tackle this but I can't find anything of help and that is why I registered myself on stackoverflow.

English is not my first language so please excuse grammatical errors.

Please help!

Comment: Are using some database to control de insert of these foods? like mariaDB or  others one. If you are not using a recommend to save these foods in a json file and let just one form to save them.

Comment: I am not so familiar with MySQL but I have added a database on phpMyAdmin at my web hoster after you wrote this and are currently watching different tutorials on YouTube how to manage the database.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using phpMyAdmin SQL with both SELECT and UPDATE in my PHP-code to handle information from tables. The summarized page also has refresh meta so if new information is made about the food from person 1 to 6 from their forms it will show it with a five second delay.

I am new to SQL and it was a bit tricky at first to get the forms to work with updating the SQL using variables in the PHP-code and also establishing a connection in the code.